# Why @GetMapping don't work, when @RequestMapping working properly?

Tags: java

I deploy my REST application on Weblogic (i don't use web.xml, version of Spring is 5.1.0). If method annotated like this all ok

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Cat searchCats(@RequestParam(name = "Name") String Name){
   //some code 
   return new Cat();
}
```

during deploy i see logs from weblogic 
Mapped 
`{[/logs],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}`

but if i annotated like this

```
@GetMapping("/logs")
 public Cat searchCats(@RequestParam(name = "Name") String Name){
    //some code 
    return new Cat();
 }
```

There is no correct mapping in ServletContex during the deploy
Mapped 
`{[],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}`

Comment: You did change `test` to `logs`.

Comment: Instead of using the @GetMapping() use @RequestMapping

Comment: Sorry, I really changed test to logs, but it is just misprint. Problem not resolvet yet. I use @RequestMapping and everything is working.

Answer (score 2):

update annotation `@GetMapping(path="/logs")`

```
@GetMapping(path="/logs")
 public Cat searchCats(@RequestParam(name = "Name") String Name){
    //some code 
    return new Cat();
 }
```

Comment: I have already tried @GetMapping(path="/logs"), and @GetMapping(value="/logs") too. But it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In @GetMapping version, you use a RequestParam, but not provide it in path. Try with:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/logs/${Name}")
```